# How do I describe a Quarter Car Suspension with differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, mathematical-modeling

So I've been struggling with describing this Quarter Car Suspension with a differential equation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The main point of difficulty for me is the fact that there are two x variables (x1 and x2) and I'm not sure which one I'm supposed to use for velocity and acceleration. I was told I should use Newton's 2nd law so I used it and ended up with these equations:

[image]

None of these look like differential equations. There are always some irrelevant x1 or x2 terms in each one. In a later part I am asked to find the space-state (the ABCD matrices) using x={x1, x'1, x2, x'2}T as a space-state vector and with w and u as inputs. I'm not sure how to go about finding the space-state with so many variables. If I'm not mistaken, the input is multiplied by D, but in this case the inputs are two (u and w).

Comment: What do do you expect differential equations to look like?

Comment: Having one value y, its first and second order derivative: ay'' + by' + cy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Newton and assuming that $u$ is a force active suspension control, we have

$$
\cases{
M\ddot x_1 = k_1(x_2-x_1)+b_1(\dot x_2-\dot x_1) + u\\
m\ddot x_2 = -k_1(x_2-x_1)-b_1(\dot x_2-\dot x_1) - u +k_2(w-x_2)+b_2(\dot w-\dot x_2)
}
$$

or

$$
\left(\matrix{
M& 0 \\ 0&m}\right)\left(\matrix{
\ddot x_1 \\ \ddot x_2}\right)=\left(\matrix{
-b_1& b_1 \\ b_1&-(b_1+b_2)}\right)\left(\matrix{
\dot x_1 \\ \dot x_2}\right)+\left(\matrix{
-k_1& k_1 \\ k_1&-(k_1+k_2)}\right)\left(\matrix{
x_1 \\ x_2}\right)+\left(\matrix{
u \\ k_2w+b_2\dot w-u}\right)
$$

now calling $y = \left(\matrix{
x_1 \\ x_2}\right)$ and $v = \left(\matrix{
u \\ k_2w+b_2\dot w - u}\right)$ we have

$$
\mathcal{M} \ddot y + \mathcal{B} \dot y + \mathcal{K} y = v
$$

or

$$
\ddot y + \mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{B}\dot y + \mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{K} y = \mathcal{M}^{-1}v
$$

Comment: This makes sense but I'm still not sure how to find the state-space of this thing. I tried the standard procedure and ended up with A = [0 1; -K/M -B/M] B = [0 1/M]. First of all, you cannot put matrices in a fraction and second I have matrices within the matrix

Comment: I would give the mass matrix a different name than $M$ because that is also the name of the scalar mass of the upper body, so this is a bit misleading. I am also not sure if these equations are correct, as in the question there are two inputs mentioned, but the question is a bit unclear about that... $w$ seems to be the street profile but it is not clear what $u$ is (maybe some sort of active damper?) Anyway, I would also choose a different name for the vector $u$, because that is also a bit misleading with the picture, where $u$ is a scalar.

Comment: @SampleTime Thanks for your comments.